# Check in all files that are checked out by me

Tags: 2010, check-in

Using SharePoint 2010 , I currently have a web part to show me a list of all documents checked out by `[ME]` (current user).

However, there are no select boxes available for those, so I cannot check in from this same web part.

How can I create a "check in all files checked out by me in this SharePoint instance" - it should work across all document libraries in this instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to check-in all checked out documents or you have to create a web part that can help you with that?

Comment: I would like a button or link on the front page that says "check in all files checked out by me" - the user already has a webpart showing them the list of files, now we need the action to check them all in at the same time accross multiple document libraries and folders.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the default `Check-In` for all files that checked out to you without coding by doing the following :

- Create a view in your document library with following columns.

[image]

- at Filter with  `Checked Out To  equal [Me]`

[image]

- At this view > select all files from the above checkbox at the Doc header, > from the above ribbon at `Items Tab` > select `check-in` to check in all files that checked out to you.

[image]

**[Update]**

To show **all files** within the document library that check out to `[Me]` Whether these files in folders and subfolders , do the following

- Modify your custom view.
- At `Folders` Section > Check `Show all items without folders`

[image]

Comment: I am fairly certain that this will only work for the folder I'm in, not recursively in folders beneath it, can you confirm?

Comment: you alright my bro and to overcome this you should check "Show all items without folders" at folder section on your custom view this will show all files check out to you in all library even if the document within folders and subfolders , should you check my updated answer , hope it helps you

Comment: Mohamed, you've saved my life! Thanks so much for this help.

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly even on the new version of sharepoint without the need for scripts, powershell, etc